# Merge two SQL selects into one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

have two SQL selects on same table. 1st select Shows desired user data. 2nd select finds how many times "initials" are used. That value tends to be used multiple times though it shouldn't

I don't want to have less rows as in query 1 but to add "Initial Count on all"

-- First Query showing all desired data

```
SELECT   
    UserID, Username, Initials
FROM     
    dbo.Users
```

This query is able to Count Initaials

```
SELECT
    Initials, count(*) as InitialCount
FROM     
    dbo.Users
GROUP BY 
    Initials
```

Output:

```
UserID  |  Username   |  Initals | Initialcount 
----------------------------------------------      
   1    |  Peter Pan  |     PP   |  2  
   2    |  Paul Pax   |     PP   |  2
   3    |  John Doe   |     JD   |  1
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` with `OVER()` to get the count per group (defined by `PARTITION BY`) without a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT   
    UserID
  , Username
  , Initials
  , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Initials) AS InitialCount
FROM     
    dbo.Users
```

Commonly referred to as analytic or window functions, `OVER()` can be used with aggregate functions like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserID, Username, Inititials, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users U2 WHERE U2.Inititals = U1.Initials) InitialCount
FROM dbo.Users U1
```

Answer (score 0):

So try using the key word distinct depending on the data you may need to do a self join.  I just learning SQL so I may not be correct.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT UserID, Username, Initials, count(Initials) as InitialCount
FROM     dbo.Users
GROUOP BY UserID
```

Comment: I don't think you can do DISTINCT and GROUP BY in one statement. GROUP BY essentially does the distinct operation for you.